# is retaining a static array makes a leak on non-arc project?

Tags: objective-c, static, nsarray, memory-leaks

I got a test code below.
(By this example I faced that an interface cannot be statically allocated without retain.)

By this codeblock I understood what really retain is.
I wantto be sure if this makes a leak and should I release it in somewhere else.
simply I dont wantto reinitialize each time the array. and made it static.(disadvantage on memory but advantage on speed)

should I release this retained static array somewhere ? is it a safe code or have I totaly remove static and retain words and just init with arrayObjects method classically ?
so what may you prefer for me ?

```
-(NSUInteger)getCoordYByX:(int)ax
{
    NSUInteger ret_=-1;

    static NSArray *coordsX=nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        coordsX=[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:170],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:190],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:210],
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:350],
                      nil]retain];
                      /*it is more longer. cropped for test purposes*/

});
    ret_=[[coordsX objectAtIndex:ax] unsignedIntegerValue];
return  ret_;
```

}

---

in conclusion:
why static doesn't keeps the array initial values? and
what If I wantto use retain, may occur a memory leak or not ?

Comment: Since it's static, it should be alive for all the program duration. Then why releasing it elsewhere? It is like a global variable, except that it's visible only in the function.

Comment: One downside of holding pointers to static data inside a function is that your function would be non-reentrant. That means that it cannot be safely called by multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: @DanielMartín Not in this case, because the array is immutable.

Comment: sorry about declaring it as a class method.
corrected question.
my question was all about class instance methods.
thus array values should live since the class instance is alive.

my question was this. if it makes a leak when the class instance is deallocated/freed/depolyed/destroyed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just one way you could declare a global, immutable array of objects.

It is not a leak in the sense that no allocation is unreachable memory. To take that example further (read: to silliness), your program could `-retain` all those objects and you would still not have a leak by definition of unreachable memory. The array is initialized exactly once and never reassigned, so that initial array will always be accessible to your method, and its elements always reachable via the array.

However, this is memory which cannot be reclaimed until the program terminates (assuming the method body is entered). So, it's really not a design I would encourage (in fact, I avoid this design).

A superior alternative would look more like:

```
+ (NSUInteger)coordYByX:(int)ax
{
 enum { NCoordsX = 5 };
 const NSUInteger CoordsX[NCoordsX] = { 50,170,190,210,350 };
 assert(ax < NCoordsX && "invalid index"); // handle error as you handle errors
 return CoordsX[ax];
}
```

This requires zero heap allocations, zero static storage, and zero locks ;)

Comment: nice answer.a better approach.
But:
Im looking about the answer. :
Just trying to understand why static doesnt keeps the initial values.
and what If I wantto use retain occurs a memory leak or not.

Comment: @N.Ramos whether it is declared inside a class method or instance method does not change my answer -- it's the same for both :)

Comment: Im appropriating your answer.Its more convenient.
but Im 
trying to understand why static doesnt keeps the array initial values. and what If I wantto use retain occurs a memory leak or not.

Comment: @N.Ramos if you want an array of objects, the program you posted is already *correct*. it will create one array of NSNumbers in a thread-safe manner, and the objects have proper reference counting. the array holds references to its elements, and the written `-retain` is a held reference for the `static` variable `coordsX` (it is necessary). the array and its elements will live until your program exits. i don't see why you see different behavior in this example.

Answer (score 1):

static is simply make your variable alive until your application quit. static declaration will not make leak. I think here there is chance to get leak in your code. Because,

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:170],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:190],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:210],
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:350],
                  nil]retain];
```

is equal to

```
[[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:170],
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:190],
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:210],
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:350],
   nil] autorelease] retain];
```

So your retain message will create a leak.

Comment: since Array is static but it is immutable andalso autorelease due to  method arrayWithObjects. if I remove retain. static keyword wont holds its values because of same issue <autorelease>

Comment: I thought, if static will also keeps the Array Values once it is allocated. but it doesn't.

Comment: are you sure if a static in an **class instance method** block will keep its values ?